# AsyncTask getting called everytime

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a `navigation drawer` containing 2 items. Now in my first item click, I load data using `asynctask` and the loaded data is populated in a listview in the corresponding fragment. Now when I switch to 2nd item, again I load data using `AsyncTask` for the 2nd fragment and show it in in listview.

> Now the problem starts. When I go back to the 1st fragment, my
>   asyncTask is called again and the data is again fetched from the
>   server, I want to prevent this and load my data directly if it has
>   been already loaded once.

Please suggest

P.S - Please ask for the code if anyone needs it.
    USERPAYFRAGMENT

```
public class UserPay extends Fragment {

ProgressDialog prg;
Properties prop;

private PrefSingleton mMyPreferences;
private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> RequestList;
HashMap<String, String> map;
UserAdapter req_adp;
ListView req;
private boolean flag;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ATTACHED", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CREATE", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_pay, container, false);

    initViews(rootView);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ONCREATEVIEW", 1000).show();
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ONACTIVITYCREATED", 1000).show();
    mMyPreferences = PrefSingleton.getInstance();
    mMyPreferences.Initialize(getActivity());
    RequestList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Resources resources = this.getResources();
    AssetManager assetManager = resources.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("jsonURL.properties");
        prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to open jsonURL property file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    req_adp = new UserAdapter(getActivity(), RequestList);
    req.setAdapter(req_adp);

    if (!flag) {
        new GetRequests().execute();
    } else {

    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ONSTART", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ONRESUME", 1000).show();
}

private void initViews(View v) {
    req = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.req_list);

}

private class GetRequests extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        prg = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        prg.setIndeterminate(true);
        prg.setMessage("Fetching Pending Requests...");
        prg.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        prg.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", mMyPreferences
                .getPreference("LoginId")));

        String error_code = null;
        Log.e("URL ", "is" + prop.getProperty("GET_REQUESTS_URL"));

        try {
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    Appconstant.GET_REQUESTS_URL, "POST", params1);

            // Check your log cat for JSON response
            Log.d("Inbox JSON: ", json.toString());

            JSONObject jsonObj = json.getJSONObject("data");
            error_code = jsonObj.getString("Error_Code");
            RequestList.clear();

            if ("1".equals(error_code)) {

                JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    JSONObject jsonObj1 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String FBankId = jsonObj1
                            .getString("payment_from_bank_id");
                    String DestBankId = jsonObj1
                            .getString("payment_to_bank_id");
                    String FBank = jsonObj1.getString("fBank");
                    String TBank = jsonObj1.getString("tBank");
                    String reason = jsonObj1.getString("payment_reason");
                    String amt = jsonObj1.getString("amount");
                    String p_type = jsonObj1.getString("payment_type");
                    String status = jsonObj1.getString("status");
                    String r_date = jsonObj1
                            .getString("request_created_date");

                    map.put("FBankId", FBankId);
                    map.put("TBankId", DestBankId);
                    map.put("SourceBank", FBank);
                    map.put("DestBank", TBank);
                    map.put("ReqDate", r_date);
                    map.put("PayReason", reason);
                    map.put("Amt", amt);
                    map.put("PayType", p_type);
                    map.put("Status", status);

                    if (status.equals("pending")) {
                        if (p_type.equals("cheque")
                                || p_type.equals("Net Banking")) {
                            RequestList.add(map);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(error_code);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (prg.isShowing()) {
            prg.cancel();
        }

        if (result == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "No User Request Details Available.Please Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        req_adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        flag = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ONPAUSE",1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ONSTOP", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroyView();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ONDESTROYVIEW", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ONDESTROY", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDetach();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ONDETACH", 1000).show();
}
}
```

Comment: I think you should provide code ( to avoid downvotes too ).

Comment: Use `FragmentTransaction` `add` instead of `replace` the first fragment remain in back stack and when you come back it won't load data again.

Comment: i think when the click event on the nav drawer you will be replacing the fragment in the main FrameLayout, so fragment is recreated everytime.Hence webservice is hit, so i think you should cache the data fetched from server via local db.

Comment: where and how you are storing downloaded data?

Comment: Local db was on my mind but I do no think using local db would be good enough.I want a more independent way,something which goes by the definition of Fragment.

Comment: i am adding the downloaded data to an arraylist.

Comment: The functionality is working correctly based on your code. fragment will be recreated while you clicking item from your navigation drawer. you can bypass by using local database, skip the request if you database is not empty. and update your data which is saved in db using periodic interval by alarm manager.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to solve

1 - store the data locally and make use stored data based on appropriate condition checks

2 - If your app is based on this 2 fragments, just create the instance of these fragments and store in in member variable of parent activity. do not give chance to recreate again and again